# BufferStrategy not working

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to do build simple gui for a game using JFrame and canvas. `Window` is a class which extends JFrame class and I am using `fillRect` method to fill rectangle of black color. Every time I run my program the frame window is not black it is of default color. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

```
package test1;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author sabertooth
 */
public class Test1 extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private final static int width=600;
    private final static int height=500;

    private Window gui;
    private Thread t;
    private boolean status=false;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Dimension d=new Dimension(width,height);
        Test1 mc=new Test1();
        mc.gui=new Window();
        mc.setPreferredSize(d);
        mc.gui.setTitle("Welcome to my game");
        mc.gui.add(mc);
        mc.gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mc.gui.setVisible(true);
        Test1 t1=new Test1();
        t1.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(status)
        {
            update();
            render();
        }
    }

    public void render(){

    }

    public void update(){
        BufferStrategy bs=getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs==null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g=bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }


    public synchronized void start(){

        setStatus(true);
        t=new Thread(this, "Game Thread");
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: DoubleDouble's answer is likely the correct one, but why JFrame I wonder? If you want to just draw on a Canvas through a BufferStrategy I'd think you'd want to bypass Swing and its internal mechanisms (such as double buffering) entirely. Otherwise you might as well draw on a JPanel inside your JFrame and have Swing do the low level stuff for you. I suggest you use a plain AWT Window.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
Test1 t1=new Test1();
t1.start();
```

You already have set up a Test1 named mc and added it to your Window. Then you create a new Test1 and tell the new one to start updating, even though it isn't added to anything.

Start mc instead...

```
mc.start();
```

You can also add this line here to have the window expand itself when it starts:

```
mc.gui.pack();
mc.gui.setVisible(true);//Set it above this line in main()
```

The code works when I do the above and use a JFrame instead of where you use Window.

Comment: I checked it and remove t1 and used mc object to call start method but still it's not showing black

Comment: still the problem continues after making above changes @DoubleDouble

Comment: No effect of g.dispose() after render :(

Comment: I followed these tutorials till no 5
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=ELshNxV9QFUOo

can u take a look and told me where I am wrong I look at them 3 4 times and not being able to find the mistake

Comment: I took the code in your example, changed the `t1.star`t to `mc.start`, and changed every `Window` to `JFrame` and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Got it I have to change window to JFrame. But I don't understand why is it so. I mean Window is also a class that extends JFrame so y cant I use window