# Why Won't the Screen Change Color?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, awt

I've been trying to fix but it never changes the screen. I'm trying to used the Graphics as seen in the `render()` method. Tell me if something is wrong inside the render method so I can relax, because I can't seem to find the problem.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static int width = 300;
public static int height = width / 16*9;
public static int scale = 3;

private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private JFrame frame;

public synchronized void start() { 
    thread = new Thread();
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try{
        thread.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    frame = new JFrame();
}

public void run() {
    while(running) {
        tick();
        render();
    }
}

void tick() {}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs==null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    bs.dispose(); 
    bs.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();

    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setTitle("Rain");
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}

}
```

Comment: You're dispose()ing your BufferStrategy before you show() it.  That can't be good.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code seems quite similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547542/bufferstrategy-not-working/20547780#20547780). I would try comparing your code to that since I think they are probably using same tutorials.

Comment: Some components need to set the opaque property to true. Could try this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a stack trace of your error.

Your render method is not even being called here.
This is because your run method is not being called at all.
The reason behind all this is that you have not passed correct Runnable object at the time of Thread creation. It creates a Thread with empty run.
In your start method, just replace

```
thread = new Thread();
```

with

```
thread = new Thread(this);
```

And it should work.
Hope this helps. Enjoy.